# choose order state and status - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, order-status

1) I am looking to achieve below status flow.

**status flow**: Approval -> Processing -> Shipping -> Delivered

I could refer [this link](http://ka.lpe.sh/2012/04/21/magento-order-state-vs-status/) for understand about order state and status but still it is confusing me while choose state and status.

Short Description of What I have done:

1. create status of APPROVAL, PROCESSING, SHIPPING, DELIVERED (**note**: it is a **status** not a state)
2. When I assigned to state, that drop down contain status list also.

[image: easy for your reference]

I am so much confused about how to utilize order state and status

please give some clarity about how to make proper state and status of above status flow.

2) I have one more doubt suppose if I use wrong combination of state and status, it will affect anything in background?

Comment: You want to change status delivered instead of pending while order placed via COD?

Comment: pending status while place the order, change status to delivered after receiving customer. is it possible in automation way?

Comment: @Nits I have updated my question